# FCM message doesn't show in the notification bar after phone restart

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to get FCM message in different situations, while the app is running in foreground or background.
In one case while I FORCE STOP the application then restarting the phone, the FCM message isn't showing in notification bar.
I assume that restarting means the FCM services should be run and I can fetch the messages.

In Android-manifest, I define RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED for a receiver to call FCM service.

Can somebody help me here ?

Comment: Can you check whether auto start is disabled for your app in system settings if you are using xiaomior huawei phones

Comment: My device is samsung galaxy note3 ...

Comment: After you Force Stop an app it will not receive any broadcast intents.  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40626941/4815718.  Stopped state is [explained here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols).

Comment: @BobSnyder: Tnx for your reply, I check this scenario for whatsapp ... I've force stopped it then restarting phone & after that send a message from another device & get push notif, what is the diffrences between whatsapp & my app ? why I can get notification in whats app ?!!

Comment: I don't know.  Hope someone else can answer.

Comment: I am also facing this issue , if user does force stop and RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED does get called. @M.Zebeleh did you able to resolve this ?

Comment: What you are doing on your BootCompleteBroadcastReceiver ? which gets the BOOT_COMPLETE callback